# Actions on Google - Mac gactions won't run

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to set up the Actions sdk as described here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk

I downloaded gactions for a Mac 64-bit machine.  If I try to open the file, it opens as text.  When I am in the folder containing gactions, I try to run `gactions init` and get the response:

> -bash: gactions: command not found

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

- Download Google gactions cli from [gaction CLI](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)
- On Mac and Linux, to make the binary executable run from terminal:

  `$ cd folder_with_gactions
  $ chmod +x gactions`
- Execute gactions

  `$ cd folder_with_gactions
  $ ./gactions init`

Also, you may find this tutorial interesting if you are trying to create an action in Google Home : [How to create a custom private Google Home Action with API.AI and Google App Engine](https://medium.com/@saracraba/how-to-create-a-custom-private-google-home-action-260e2c512fc). In ***STEP 8*** you can find an example of gactions.

Comment: Hi, I did these exact steps, however I still can't type `gactions` in my terminal or iterm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039531/cant-install-gactions-cli

Answer (score 2):

If you have already setup google-cloud-sdk correctly, then you can drop the gactions file into the google-cloud-sdk/bin folder. Alternatively, you can add a path to bash directly to the folder you have gactions.

Answer (score 1):

To add the **gactions** command CLI location to the System Paths:

1. Use “Go to the Folder” option of Finder, to search “~/.bash_profile”
2. Open the File “~/.bash_profile”  in edit mode and add the following command, at the top the file, Save and Close.

   **export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/gactionsCLI"**

   > Note: Above path refers to the folder which contains the executable
   >   file “Unix Executable”
3. Restart the Terminal and try the commands

Answer (score 0):

Download [gactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

copy downloaded gactions and put into a local Project folder

and  then go to your project directory cd "**project directory**"

run following commands :

```
$ chmod +x gactions

$ ./gactions init
```

it will create ***action.json*** into your folder

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure you run **chmod +x gactions** to make the binary executable
- Copy the binary executable into the project directory
- Run **./gactions init** from the terminal/command line