# Can't install gactions CLI

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, actions-on-google

I'm trying to install the google actions CLI.

The docs: https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli

I followed the [commands here](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) as well as from the [question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452523/actions-on-google-mac-gactions-wont-run).

I downloaded the Mac x86_64.

Then ran the following command on it: `Run chmod +x gactions to make the binary executable.`

It did turn the file into an executable. When I clicked it, it opened in terminal and did something.

[image]

However in a new tab in terminal it still does not understand the gactions.

[image]

Also I don't use terminal but iterm2, so I tried opening the executable in iterm2 and got this error.

[image]

### How to update $PATH

I placed the gactions file here

[image]

My current $PATHs

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export GOOGLE_SDK_PATH="/Users/leongaban/Projects/YumBrands/GoogleHome"
export TERM="xterm-256color"
export NODE_ENV
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gactions` file you downloaded is the executable itself - not an installer or anything along those lines. You can put it somewhere in your PATH or call it directly by giving the full path when you're calling it, but it will not be automatically available unless you do so.

You can see your PATH with `echo $PATH`. If you wish, you can place it in one of those directories.

If you wish to continue to run it out of your Download directory (which I do, since I rarely use the command), you can open an iterm2 command line and call gactions with the full path:

```
~/Downloads/gactions
```

or (using your example)

```
~/Projects/YumBrands/GoogleHome/gactions
```

Or (also using your example) you could add the following line (probably to your ~/.zshrc file) to reference the gactions command in the GoogleHome directory:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Projects/YumBrands/GoogleHome"
```

You can then open a new terminal or iterm2 window and confirm that this is in your path

```
echo $PATH
```

The normal way to use it would be to create a directory where you are developing your Action (I use ~/Documents/Projects) and have gactions create the default `action.json` file. Possibly something like this:

```
mkdir ~/Documents/Projects/new-sample-action
cd  ~/Documents/Projects/new-sample-action
~/Downloads/gactions init
```

(If you have updated your PATH, you can just use `gactions init` for the last line.)

Comment: Hi thanks, I still cannot use the `gactions` keyword to call init. I've updated my question with a screenshot of where I placed the `gactions` file, it was in Downloads. Also pasted my current $PATHs, what should they be changed too?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Keep in mind that you don't NEED to add the directory with it to your PATH. You can always call the full path to the command.

Comment: For Leon or future readers - Don't forget you have to RESTART any zsh(/bash etc) shells if you have edited PATH in ~/.zshrc (etc) . Prisoner has given all the deets.

Comment: For future readers, my ~/.zshrc file already included a path to $HOME/bin so I simply moved the gactions executable to that directory and it worked fine without having to edit anything.

Answer (score 1):

Download [gactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

copy downloaded gactions and put into a local Project folder

and  then go to your project directory cd "**project directory**"

run following commands :

```
$ chmod +x gactions

$ ./gactions init
```

it will create ***action.json*** into your folder

Answer (score 0):

Go to the corresponding Path where you have downloaded the gactions file.

```
chmod +x gactions
./gactions help
```

You can use gactions by ./gactions. It worked for me.